# How to setup a 404 route in Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-status-code-404

How do I set up a 404 route in Node/Express? If the URL is not valid, I want to render an HTML or Handlebars file to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you have an express app like this:

```
const app = express()
```

then put all your routes and at the end of all your routes put 404 route like:

```js
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    success: false,
    message: "Page not found",
  });
});
```

if you are using handlbars or any other template engine, you can do it like:

```js
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.render('404.html')
});
```